# Attaching eonasdan-datetimepicker to dynamically created element returns "relative positioned container" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have the following input, which I'm attaching datetimepicker to on pageload:

[image: Screenshot 1]

This works as expected.

When the user clicks a button, I duplicate this input to allow for multiple dates.

Clone code:

[image: Screenshot 2]

The cloning works as expected, but clicking the date input triggers this error:

**Uncaught Error: datetimepicker component should be placed within a relative positioned container**

[image]

`.input-group` already has `"position: relative;"` set in a separate CSS file. I tried adding this as an inline style, but id didn't make a difference.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Swapped the order of my `.datetimepicker` and `insertAfter` functions. Was trying to add a datetimepicker to an input that didn't yet exist.